# MSSQL: refer to other table several times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Unfortunately, I didn't find a reference to this although it shouldn't be a very common problem.

I have two tables:

```
TABLE d

Date   ClientID1 ClientID2 ClientID3
1.1.10    1          2         3
```

and

```
TABLE c

ClientID   Name
    1      abc
    2      def
    3      ghi
```

I would like to create the following table:

```
Date   ClientID1   NameID1   ClientID2   NameID2   ClientID3   NameID3
1.1.10     1         abc         2         def         3         ghi
```

I am aware that I could solve this with nested queries, eg with

```
SELECT e.*, c.Name AS NameID2
FROM (
   SELECT d.*, c.Name AS NameID1
   FROM d, c
   WHERE d.ClientID1=c.ClientID
   ) AS e, c
WHERE d.ClientID2=c.ClientID
... and so on
```

However, this solution is not at all elegant, and I think there should be a better solution (particularly if we have many more columns where we want to do that).

Comment: So you want to join table c three times to get the names? You can, just give them aliases so they’re different. No need for any subqueries

Comment: This looks like a typical crosstab or pivot. And you really need to stop using the antiquated ANSI-89 style join syntax. The "newer" ANSI-92 style has been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: The biggest issue here however is that your first table is not normalized which is causing you challenges. If at all possible normalize that so you don't have repeating columns.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: I don't understand what you mean. Could you clarify this?

Comment: @SeanLange: you are absolutely right - I didn't use SQL for a long time and I was very used to the ANSI-89 style, but it is really true that ANSI-92 is much more readable. The first table in fact is normalized, as the three clients have different roles such as supplier and customers, and the same parties can be suppliers or customers. I just simplified my request.

Comment: The normalization bit makes sense now. It was just the names used here that made it look wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `apply` with *conditional* aggregation  :

```
select d.date,
       max(case when client = 'ClientID1' then ClientID end) AS [ClientID1],
       max(case when client = 'ClientID1' then Name end) AS [NameID],
       . . . 
from d cross apply
     ( values ('ClientID1', ClientID1), ('ClientID2', ClientID2), ('ClientID3', ClientID3)  
     ) dd (client, c_value) inner join
     c 
     on c.ClientID = dd.c_value
group by d.date;
```